# Function to Substitute Group-By Condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

[image]

As the pic shows, I want to define a variable `groupTerm` so when I group by, I can group by my data frame however I define the `groupTerm`
(i.e.

`groupTerm <- "month" ----> df %>% group_by (month)`;

`groupTerm <- "date" ----> df %>% group_by (date)`.

However, it seems in the `group_by` clause, the term `groupTerm` must be an actual column name in the data frame, which gives me an epic fail.

Can someone give me an idea on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Change your line to `group_by( {{ groupTerm }} )`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `ensym` with `!!` which can take both quoted and unquoted value

```
 func <- function(groupTerm, print = TRUE) {
            df %>% 
                 group_by(!! ensym(groupTerm)) %>%
                 summarise(min_date = min(date))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Phil's idea, I solved this question.

Having

```
func <-
function(groupTerm, print = TRUE){
  f_df <-
  df %>% 
    group_by({groupTerm})
```

I then assigned to `groupTerm <- df$month` instead of `groupTerm <- 'month'`